# Start an Activity from a non-Activity class

Tags: java, android, android-activity

I'm making a small game using Android Studio which has 3 activities: Menu, Main(Game), WinScreen. When I try to go from Menu to Main or WinScreen to Main it works perfectly fine, but when I try to launch an activity from the Main activity I get an error.

I have a method in a java file that checks if the player won and if that's the case it is supposed to launch the WinScreen activity.

```
boolean checkWin(GameBoard gameboard){
       if(compareTabs(gameboard) == true){
           System.out.println("Win !");
           Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this,WinActivity.class);
           startActivity(i);
           return true;
       }
       else{
           return false;
       }
}
```

And this is the error I get:

> error: not an enclosing class: MainActivity

This method is located in a file called GameBoard, GameBoard is used by the GameView Class who is launched at the start of the MainActivity

I know there is hundreds of posts similar to mine but I've pretty much tried everything I've found already and nothing seems to work and I'm pretty sure it's a really dumb issue.

I've already tried things like `Intent i = new Intent(this,WinActivity.class);`

Comment: It is useless to refer to `MainActivity.this` while not being within it's `Context`.

Comment: @MartinZeitler Yes but I dont know how to get my activity's context .

Comment: Why don't you just do the `startActivity()` in `MainActivity` if `checkWin()` returns `true`?

Comment: From where you calling this method?

Comment: Add more details about `checkWin` environment

Comment: I really think that you need to brush up your java concept first ..you can not reference `this` for an object from an another class with no relationship.

Comment: What class is `checkWin()` a part of? Show the `class` definition for that class (ie: `extends ... implements ...`)

Answer (score 0):

> Note that if this method is being called from outside of an Activity
>   Context, then the Intent must include the
>   **Intent#FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK** launch flag. This is because, without
>   being started from an existing Activity, there is no existing task in
>   which to place the new activity and thus it needs to be placed in its
>   own separate task.

[Android developer documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#startActivity%28android.content.Intent%29)

Answer (score 0):

Change the signature of `checkWin()` to include a `Context` as a parameter and then use that `Context` here:

```
boolean checkWin(GameBoard gameboard, Context context){
   if(compareTabs(gameboard) == true){
       System.out.println("Win !");
       Intent i = new Intent(context, WinActivity.class);
       context.startActivity(i);
       return true;
   }
   else{
       return false;
   }
}
```

If you are calling `checkWin()` from an `Activity`, you can just provide `this` as the `Context` parameter when calling it, because `Activity` is a `Context`:

```
(inside an Activity)
boolean win = whatever.checkWin(gameboard, this);
```